# Using a Guid Version column in NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, version

We are working with a legacy database that uses SQL server uniqueidentifier columns for concurrency hence we need to use a Guid as a version column. Any idea how we could achieve this in NHibernate?

We're currently defining our mapping using Fluent NHibernate as a Guid typed property called ConcurrencyId using this snippet

`Version(x => x.ConcurrencyId)`

This results in the following error when creating a session

`System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Type.GuidType' to type 'NHibernate.Type.IVersionType'.`

Any ideas on how this could be done, fluently or otherwise would be appreciated. We're happy to hack the source if it can be made to work.

Comment: What happens to the guid when the next version is generated? Increase it with one byte on the end? Is Guid.empty unsaved?

Comment: I imagine you'd create a new Guid? Kind of like timestamp data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try implementing a custom type implementing [`NHibernate.UserTypes.IUserVersionType`](https://github.com/ayende/nhibernate/blob/master/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/UserTypes/IUserVersionType.cs). (I think this suggestion may pertain to a newer version of NHibernate than you are using.)

Comment: This works with FluentNHibernate 1.1. I've posted the code on my blog http://www.alexlea.me/2010/11/using-guid-as-version-column-in.html. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this...

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/15/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency.aspx

and the docs for the version property

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-version

Looks like you can't use a Guid for this. Maybe just map it as a property and handle the version checks yourself.